# Combine / Merge Multiple Arrays Into One

Tags: arrays, swift, iphone, variables, merge

I have four list of arrays:

```
var products: [Product] = []
var addressInfo: [AddressInfo] = []
var favorites: [Favorite] = []
var amounts: [Amount] = []
```

I want to combine them all into one so I have only one variable:

```
var combined = [Product/AddressInfo/Favorite/Amount]()
```

How would I go about merging them into one array `var cobmbined = [Combined]()` ?

This these are two examples of how my structs look like:

```
struct Amount {
    var amountsDeliveryCharge: Double
    var amountsDriverTip: Double
    init(        
        amountsDeliveryCharge: Double,
        amountsDriverTip: Double
        ){
        self.amountsDeliveryCharge = amountsDeliveryCharge
        self.amountsDriverTip = amountsDriverTip
    }

    init(data: [String: Any]){
        amountsDeliveryCharge = data[DatabaseRef.deliveryCharge] as? Double ?? 0.0
        amountsDriverTip = data[DatabaseRef.driverTip] as? Double ?? 0.0
    }

    static func modelToData(amount: Amount) -> [String: Any] {        
        let data : [String: Any] = [
            DatabaseRef.deliveryCharge : amount.amountsDeliveryCharge,
            DatabaseRef.driverTip : amount.amountsDriverTip
        ]
        return data
    }   
}
```

This is the other struct:

```
struct Product {
    var price: Double
    var priceUnit: String        
    init(
        price: Double,
        priceUnit: String    
        ){
        self.price = price
        self.priceUnit = priceUnit
    }

    init(data: [String: Any]){    
        price = data[DatabaseRef.price] as? Double ?? 0.0
        priceUnit = data[DatabaseRef.priceUnit] as? String ?? ""
    }

    static func modelToData(product: Product) -> [String: Any] {            
        let data : [String: Any] = [
            DatabaseRef.price : product.price,
            DatabaseRef.priceUnit : product.priceUnit

        ]
        return data
    }
}
```

The other two structs look similar in structure as well.

Comment: Do you have already a custom struct that has a property Product, one AddressInfo, another Favorite and another Amount? (Combined?) Also, I guess that you want to merge products[i] with addressInfo[i] favorites[i] & amounts[i]?

Comment: @Larme I just edited my post including two structs as an example. I simply need to combine them into one at the end. I dont have a struct for the `Combined` one.

Comment: `var combined = [Product/AddressInfo/Favorite/Amount]()` is unclear. Can you give an example?

Comment: The actual contents of the structs should be irrelevant - they are there own types.  Do you mean you want an array that can contained heterogenous elements, eg. [product1, product2, amount5, favourite3, amount1] or do you want to group them as their own entities eg.  [combined1, combined2, combined3] where each Combined contains all the types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the ordering is the same in each of them, create a struct with the appropriate properties

```
struct Combined {
  let product: Product
  let addressInfo: AddressInfo
  let favourite: Favourite
  let amount: Amount
}
```

and then either loop through the arrays using a counter to index then and create instances using the memberWise initialiser, or use a static factory function to make and return the array:

```
static func makeFrom(products: [Product], addresses: [AddressInfo], favourites: [Favourite], amounts: [Amount]) -> [Combined] {
  guard products.count == addresses.count, addresses.count == favourites.count, favourites.count == amounts.count else {fatalError()}. //handle better in practice
  var combined = [Combined]()
  for index in 0..<products.count {
    combined.append(Combined(product: products[index],
                             addressInfo: addresses[index],
                             favourite: favourites[index],
                             amount: amounts[index])
  }
  return combined
}
```

The above checks that all arrays are teh same length and if not calls `fatalError()`.  In reality you'd want to handle the error better than this.

Then use as:

```
let combined = Combined.makeFrom(products: products, addresses:addressInfo, favourites: favourites, amounts: amounts)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ordering is the same in each of them" ? Like the count for each? If so; they are not the same. The count for one variable can be 2 and another 4 or 10 or the same.

Comment: @Farhadam they thought there was a 1:1:1:1 mapping between products, addresses, favourites, and amounts and those together would equal one combined value of which the array would be composed of. Look at [my response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59379075/11735828) to accomplish what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your arrays as [Any] and add them.

```
let combinedVals = (products as [Any]) + (addressInfo as [Any]) + (favorites as [Any]) + (amounts as [Any])
```

Alternatively you can create a protocol and have your structs adhere to it.

```
protocol Combined {
}
struct Amount: Combined {
    var amountsDeliveryCharge: Double
    var amountsDriverTip: Double
}
struct Product: Combined  {
    var price: Double
    var priceUnit: String
}

let combinedValues: [Combined] = amounts + products
```

When you iterate over the array, if you need to check what it is, you can use a switch to check it's type.

```
combinedValues.forEach { (value) in
    switch value {
        case let value as Amount:
            print(value.amountsDriverTip)
        break
        case let value as Product:
            print(value.price)
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```